# I have encountered "Buffer overflow-array index out of bounds" error

Tags: c, c-strings, strcpy, strcat, strncpy

I do understand the error but don't know what is the proper solution for this. It says

> Array 'filename' of size 512 may use index value(s) MIN..1022

Is it because `strncat` is called right after `strncpy`?

I tried doing `strlen`, but that introduced some other errors.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 512
void some_function(const char *path)        /*path is also char  
                                             array of size 512*/  
{

    char filename[MAX_SIZE]="";
    char *attr = "/funct";

    strncpy(filename, path, sizeof(filename));
    strncat(filename, attr, sizeof(filename));  //error line

}
```

Is there any proper solution for this.

Comment: `path` is considered an `int`. Declare as: `void some_function(char *path)`.

Comment: `strncpy` does not terminate the copied string if more is attempted to be copied than the size parameter. `strncat` will then atempt to search the end, but there may not be a terminating null character.

Comment: And turn warnings of your compiler ON.

Comment: In the `strncat` call you have to specify the remaining space, something like `sizeof(filename)-strlen(filename)`.

Comment: and please note that a) `strncpy()` doesn't write a `'\0'` to `filename` if `strlen(PATH) >= MAX_SIZE` and b) `strncat()` appends up to another `MAX_SIZE` characters to `filename` thus potentially exceeding the array size

Comment: To terminate the `strncpy`d string: `filename[sizeof(filename)-1]= '\0';`

Comment: @paul: filename array is fully initialized with 0's in the above case.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(filename)` is `MAX_SIZE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the function `strncpy` then you have to set its last character to the zero character '\0'. Otherwise you can not guarantee that the character array contains a string.

Using `strncat` this way

```
strncat(filename, attr, sizeof(filename));
```

does not make sense. The array `filename` can have no enough space to accommodate the string `attr`. But you are trying to copy `sizeof(filename)` characters to an array that already can be entirely filled.

You have to check "manually" whether the destination array contains enough space to append a new string to the already stored string.

So there is no sense to use the function `strncat` because in any case the result path will be invalid.

You can use the following approach shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 512

void some_function(const char *path )
{
    char filename[MAX_SIZE] = "";
    const char *attr = "/funct";
    size_t n = strlen( attr );

    strncpy( filename, path, sizeof (filename ) );

    filename[ MAX_SIZE - 1] = '\0';

    if ( n < MAX_SIZE - strlen( filename ) )
    {
        strcat( filename, attr ); 
    }

    puts( filename );
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *path = "/path";

    some_function( path );

    return 0;
}
```

Or you could at the very beginning of the function check whether the array can contain the both strings. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 512

void some_function(const char *path )
{
    char filename[MAX_SIZE] = "";
    const char *attr = "/funct";
    size_t n1 = strlen( path );
    size_t n2 = strlen( attr );

    if ( n1 + n2 < MAX_SIZE )
    {
        strcpy( filename, path );

        strcpy( filename + n1, attr ); 
    }

    puts( filename );
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *path = "/path";

    some_function( path );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message of the compiler is probably because you copy a maximum of 511 bytes (plus null) and then concatenate another maximum of 511 bytes (plus null), a total of 1022 bytes (plus one null).

However, the compiler sees the target is only 512 bytes and issues a warning.

Solutions are given in comments and in other solutions, which I do not repeat here.